# I want to integrate Square API and Stripe API in single platform, both should function same way, below are my queries where I'm unable to find answer

Tags: stripe-payments, square, square-connect

My current application have stripe API integrated I want to integrate square API.

I'm stuck at a place where we can charge application fee in stripe how can we apply similar way in square API.

Also how can I create recurring charges like we can do it in Stripe API with the help of subscription, plan and product.

Comment: Square do not have automatic recurring payments. Your closest option is saving a card on file, and then charging the card at some interval (manually) https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/transactions/processing-recurring-payments-ruby?q=recurring - Square Team

Comment: First point - after you've gotten access to the other merchant's account via OAuth, when calling `Charge` you will set `additional_recipients` to use your own developer `location_id` and the 2% fee set in `amount_money`. https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/transactions/setup#optional-split-transactions-with-additional-recipients

Comment: Just checking in - did these answer your question? I believe we spoke our on Slack channel, so just wanted to make sure you're all set now.

Comment: @sjosey Yes we talked on Slack and these solutions helped in a way, however is there a way to have multiple `additional_recipients` ?

Comment: Not at this time. The `additional_recipients` must provide a `location_id` which must be the app owner's location.